# Accessing array's contents iOS 6

Tags: json, api, ios6, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm new to coding and was wondering if anyone out there could help me. I am using a web service for the first time. I am having trouble accessing any of the array though. I can't get anything out.

Now I can successfully get the information from the web service and store it in an NSArray. I NSLog it and low and behold the contents appears in my console. I check the count of the array and it is 5.

But I am unable to access any of the contents. The error states:CustomTableView[4083:11303] -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xff231b0

I just really want to know how to access various values within the array. Thanks in advance for your help! :)

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *searchedYummlyRecipeList;

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    self.searchedYummlyRecipeList = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.yummlyRecipesData options:nil error:nil];
    //test logging
    NSLog(@"Recipe List: %@ ", self.searchedYummlyRecipeList);//prints fine
    NSLog(@"Count of test array: %lu", (unsigned long)[self.searchedYummlyRecipeList count]);//prints fine 
    NSArray *testArray = [[self.searchedYummlyRecipeList objectAtIndex:1]objectForKey:@"criteria"];//breakpoint is here
    NSLog(@"test Array: %@", testArray);//doesn't get here
    NSLog(@"test Array count: %lu", (unsigned long)[testArray count]);//doesn't get here

}
```

Extract of nslog output:

```
 Recipe List: {
attribution =     {
    html = "<a href='http://www.yummly.com/recipes/onion-soup'>onion soup recipes</a> search powered by <img src='http://static.yummly.com/api-logo.png'/>";
    logo = "http://static.yummly.com/api-logo.png";
    text = "onion soup recipes: search powered by Yummly";
    url = "http://www.yummly.com/recipes/onion-soup";
};
criteria =     {
    allowedIngredients =         (
    );
    excludedIngredients =         (
    );
    facetFields =         (
    );
    maxResults = 6;
    requirePictures = 0;
    resultsToSkip = 0;
    terms =         (
        onion,
        soup
    );
};
facetCounts =     {
};
matches =     (
            {
        attributes =             {
            course =                 (
                Soups,
                Appetizers
            );
            cuisine =                 (
                French
            );
            holiday =                 (
                Thanksgiving
            );
        };
        flavors =             {
            bitter = "0.1666666666666667";
            meaty = "0.1666666666666667";
            piquant = 0;
            salty = "0.1666666666666667";
            sour = "0.1666666666666667";
            sweet = "0.1666666666666667";
        };
        id = "French-Onion-Soup-The-Pioneer-Woman-Cooks-_-Ree-Drummond-41364";
        ingredients =             (
            "beef broth",
            "minced garlic",
            "stick butter",
            "yellow onion",
            "french bread",
            "worcestershire sauce",
            "gruyere cheese",
            "low sodium chicken broth",
            "dry white wine"
        );
        rating = 0;
        recipeName = "French Onion Soup";
        smallImageUrls =             (
            "http://i.yummly.com/French-Onion-Soup-The-Pioneer-Woman-Cooks-_-Ree-Drummond-41364-1512.s.jpg",
            "http://i.yummly.com/French-Onion-Soup-The-Pioneer-Woman-Cooks-_-Ree-Drummond-41364-1199.s.jpg",
            "http://i.yummly.com/French-Onion-Soup-The-Pioneer-Woman-Cooks-_-Ree-Drummond-41364-220.s.jpg"
        );
        sourceDisplayName = "The Pioneer Woman";
        totalTimeInSeconds = 0;
    },
            {
        attributes =             {
            course =                 (
                "Main Dishes"
            );
        };
        flavors =             {
            bitter = 1;
            meaty = "0.1666666666666667";
            piquant = 0;
            salty = 1;
            sour = "0.1666666666666667";
            sweet = "0.3333333333333333";
        };
        id = "Awesome-Slow-Cooker-Pot-Roast-Allrecipes";
        ingredients =             (
            "onion soup mix",
            "condensed cream of mushroom soup",
            "pot roast",
            water
        );
        rating = "4.69";
        recipeName = "Awesome Slow Cooker Pot Roast";
        smallImageUrls =             (
            "http://i2.yummly.com/Awesome-Slow-Cooker-Pot-Roast-Allrecipes-2.s.png",
            "http://i.yummly.com/Awesome-Slow-Cooker-Pot-Roast-Allrecipes-58919.s.png"
        );
        sourceDisplayName = AllRecipes;
        totalTimeInSeconds = 29400;
    },
            {
        attributes =             {
            course =                 (
                Soups
            );
        };
        flavors =             {
            bitter = "0.1666666666666667";
            meaty = "0.1666666666666667";
            piquant = "0.6666666666666666";
            salty = "0.1666666666666667";
            sour = "0.1666666666666667";
            sweet = "0.1666666666666667";
        };
        id = "Chicken-Soup-for-Knaidelach-The-Shiksa-Blog-48854";
        ingredients =             (
            "sea salt",
            "bay leave",
            onions,
            giblets,
            "fresh dill",
            "curly-leaf parsley",
            "whole cloves",
            "chopped leaves",
            "black peppercorns",
            carrot
        );
        rating = 0;
        recipeName = "Chicken Soup for Knaidelach";
        smallImageUrls =             (
            "http://i.yummly.com/Chicken-Soup-for-Knaidelach-The-Shiksa-Blog-48854-10792.s.png",
            "http://i.yummly.com/Chicken-Soup-for-Knaidelach-The-Shiksa-Blog-48854-10711.s.png",
            "http://i.yummly.com/Chicken-Soup-for-Knaidelach-The-Shiksa-Blog-48854-10617.s.png"
        );
        sourceDisplayName = "The Shiksa in the Kitchen";
        totalTimeInSeconds = 10800;
    },
            {
        attributes =             {
            course =                 (
                Soups
            );
            cuisine =                 (
                American
            );
        };
        flavors = "<null>";
        id = "Chicken-Soup-The-Pioneer-Woman-200156";
        ingredients =             (
            ribs,
            carrots,
            chicken,
            "bay leaf",
            salt,
            parsnips,
            "black pepper",
            onion,
            "chicken broth"
        );
        rating = 0;
        recipeName = "Chicken Soup";
        smallImageUrls =             (
            "http://i.yummly.com/Chicken-Soup-The-Pioneer-Woman-200156-39944.s.png"
        );
        sourceDisplayName = "The Pioneer Woman";
        totalTimeInSeconds = 0;
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Recipe List is a dictionary, not an array. The value at the 'criteria' key is also a dictionary (a dictionary that happens to contain some array values).

To get the criteria dictionary you can do this:

```
NSDictionary *criteria = self.searchedYummlyRecipeList[@"criteria"];
```

You should of course also fix your @property declaration:

`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *searchedYummlyRecipeList;`

### Edit

So to take this further to get values from the criteria dictionary you might do:

`NSNumber *maxResults = criteria[@"maxResults"];`

Or alternatively, you can use a keypath to get a specific value:

`NSString *url = [self.searchedYummlyRecipeList valueForKeyPath:@"attribution.url"];`

Matches on the other hand, is an array. If you want to look at the first match, for example:

```
NSArray *matches = self.searchedYummlyRecipeList[@"matches"];
NSDictionary *firstMatch = matches[0];
NSString *firstMatchID = firstMatch[@"id"];
```

Comment: Note that the above notation with the `[]` is a new feature with the latest compilers.  For an NSDictionary it translates (inside the compiler) into the "objectForKey" call.  Even though the new notation is convenient, it's important to understand the underlying implementation.

Comment: Firoze thanks a lot. I've changed it to a NSDictionary and now can get criteria. Much appreciated. You're a life saver! However my question was a bit more generic. Do you know how I get values. For example how would I drill down further to get lets say 'maxResults' or matches 'cuisine' for arguments sake.

Comment: After the changes you recommended when I nslog'd my output was: test Array after stackoverflow: {
    allowedIngredients =     (
    );
    excludedIngredients =     (
    );
    facetFields =     (
    );
    maxResults = 6;
    requirePictures = 0;
    resultsToSkip = 0;
    terms =     (
        onion,
        soup
    );
}
Just in case your curious. :)

Comment: @Anthony - I like to say "peel the onion".  Drill in one level, NSLog what you got to be sure it's what's expected, then do the next level of access.  Assuming this is a JSON-like structure you have either an array (`()`) or dictionary (`{}`) or a simple character string/number at each level.  Peel off layers until you get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

"[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector" is telling you that the "objectAtIndex" selector (method) was "sent" to (called with) an object that is an NSDictionary.  But objectAtIndex is not a method of NSDictionary, hence the error.

It's not clear what "array" you were trying to access, but it isn't an array, it's a "dictionary" -- a key->value mapping object.  You'd use "objectForKey" to access it.

Note that it's quite easy to get the wrong type into a variable in Objective-C.  Just because a variable is typed "NSArray*" does not mean it really is an NSArray -- you could have, eg, gotten a dictionary rather than an array from a JSON parser (because that's what the JSON "says").

In your above listing, "searchedYummlyRecipeList" definitely an NSDictionary -- the `{}` characters in an NSLog indicate that.  (An array would be surrounded by `()` instead.)

Comment: Hi Hot Licks. Thanks for your answer, much appreciated. I have peeled away as suggested. I am now trying to get the recipe name but can not seem to set the text of the cell. I have no idea why? Are you able to lend any suggestions?

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"searchedRecipeCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    NSDictionary *criteria = [self.searchedYummlyRecipeList[@"matches"]objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *string = [criteria objectForKey:@"recipeName"];
    NSLog(@"This is the string from the cell: %@", string);
    cell.textLabel.text = string;
    //return configured cell
    return cell;
}

Comment: Past your JSON (not the above NSLog output) into [this page](http://json.parser.online.fr/) and it will display it nicely formatted, so it's easier to understand.  "matches" contains (close as I can decode) an array, the elements of which contain "attributes", "flavors", "id", "ingredients", "rating", "recipeName", "smallImageUrls", "sourceDisplayName", and "totalTimeInSeconds".  If you're getting the recipeName string OK then there's something wrong with you UI code, and you'd need to post that.

Comment: When I nslog I get null. I have added nslog's in other methods. It appears that cellForRowAtIndexPath: is happening before connection:didReceiveData:. So I added a refresh button. But even when it is pressed I still can't see output.

Comment: - (IBAction)refreshRecipe:(id)sender
{

    NSDictionary *criteria = [self.searchedYummlyRecipeList[@"matches"]objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *string = [criteria objectForKey:@"recipeName"];
    NSLog(@"This is the string from the cell in refresh Recipe: %@", string);
    
    [self.searchedRecipeTableView reloadData];
   

}

Comment: You get null where?  Log "criteria" and "recipeName".  "criteria" should contain `{... recipeName = "French onion soup", ...}`

Comment: (When you're first learning this stuff you need to log EVERY step along the way.)

Comment: Hi Hot Licks - I'm still attempting to print this recipe name and I have encountered a very strange scenario. I am unable to load the page/tableview. I have nslog's the view did load method and it begins and ends. It then goes into the cellforRowAtIndexPath method. It begins (nslog'd) but does not end. I am unable to return a cell. This was literally working earlier and now has decided not to. This may sound strange but could this occur because the web service I am using is down? I'm just not to sure why is could not be working? Any ideas?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The output in xcode: self SearchRecipeViewController * 0x07518300
UITableViewController UITableViewController 
_yummlyRecipesData NSMutableData * 0x00000000
_searchedRecipeTableView UITableView * 0x081c0a00
_criteria NSDictionary * 0x00000000
_searchRecipeResults NSDictionary * 0x00000000
cell UITableViewCell * 0x07131060

Comment: @Anthony - Have you ever done a table view before?  It sounds like you're probably blowing up in cellForRowAtIndexPath, and there are a dozen different ways to bobble that.

Comment: Hot licks - I tweaked the tableview methods slightly and still no luck. However the debugger now focuses on the line: @property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *searchRecipeResults;
I tried to alloc init it in the view did load. The view did load does not complete now. Do you think it could be something wrong with the nsdictionary?

Comment: p.s I swapped @property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *searchRecipeResults; for //@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *searchedYummlyRecipeList; FYI.

Comment: You're confusing yourself.  Get back to what you know and do things one step at a time.  (There should be no need to init that value, so long as it's set in your `connectionDidFinishLoading` method and you don't reference it until after that.)

Comment: ok, just started again i.e. deleted view controller and created a new one. Literally stepped through it, copied virtually all of the same code from the old one. And it works now. :-S Oh well. Thanks for your help.